# Need help in Visual Basic program

Tags: database, vb.net

I am trying to fix this code in VB and I get the following error:

> Severity: Error
>   Code: BC30516
>   Description: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Value' accepts this number of arguments.
>   Project: Database Without Code
>   File: C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\University Work\VisualBasic\Database Without Code\Database Without Code\Database.vb
>   Line: 101
>   Suppression State: Active

How do I fix this?

```
Public Class Database

    Private m_cnADOConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Private m_rstAddress As New ADODB.Recordset

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        m_cnADOConnection.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source= AddressBook.mdb") ' connects and sets path for database
        m_rstAddress.Open("tblContacts", m_cnADOConnection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        ShowCurrentRecord() 'calls a method to fill the record set
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal ' opens form in different states


    End Sub



    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        ShowCurrentRecord()
        Dim Search As String
        Dim SearchLoop As Boolean = False ' sets the loop control 
        Search = InputBox("Enter Surname: ", "Search")
        m_rstAddress.MoveFirst() ' set db to start of file

        If IsNumeric(Search) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Data: Surname must not be numeric", "Invalid Data")
            Exit Sub ' check that valid entry has been made
        End If
        Do While SearchLoop = False
            If m_rstAddress.EOF() Then
                MessageBox.Show("No Matching Records Found !", "Nil Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                SearchLoop = True
            ElseIf Search = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Surname").Value) Then
                ShowCurrentRecord()
                SearchLoop = True
            Else
                m_rstAddress.MoveNext()
            End If

        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowCurrentRecord()

        If m_rstAddress.BOF Or m_rstAddress.EOF Then
            txtFirstName.Text = ""
            txtLastName.Text = ""
            txtAddress1.Text = ""
            txtAddress2.Text = ""
            txtAddress3.Text = ""
            txtPostCode.Text = ""
            txtPhone.Text = ""
            txtEmail.Text = ""
            txtNotes.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If


        txtFirstName.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("FirstName").Value) ' the following assigns the text box the value from the DB
        txtLastName.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Surname").Value)
        txtAddress1.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Address1").Value)
        txtAddress2.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Address2").Value)
        txtAddress3.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Address3").Value)
        txtPostCode.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Postcode").Value)
        txtPhone.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value)
        txtEmail.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Email").Value)
        txtNotes.Text = CStr(m_rstAddress.Fields("Notes").Value)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click


        txtFirstName.Text = ""
        txtLastName.Text = ""
        txtAddress1.Text = ""
        txtAddress2.Text = ""
        txtAddress3.Text = ""
        txtPostCode.Text = ""
        txtPhone.Text = ""
        txtEmail.Text = ""
        txtNotes.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the details in the boxes then click Save Record", "Instructions")


    End Sub



    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click


        m_rstAddress.AddNew()

        m_rstAddress.Fields("FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Surname").Value = txtLastName.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address1").Value = txtAddress1.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address2").Value = txtAddress2.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address3").Value = txtAddress3.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value(-lblPhone.Text)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

        m_rstAddress.AddNew()

        m_rstAddress.Fields("FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Surname").Value = txtLastName.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address1").Value = txtAddress1.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address2").Value = txtAddress2.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Address3").Value = txtAddress3.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Postcode").Value = txtPostCode.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value = txtPhone.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Email").Value = txtEmail.Text
        m_rstAddress.Fields("Notes").Value = txtNotes.Text
        m_rstAddress.Update()
        ShowCurrentRecord()
        If m_rstAddress.EOF Then
            m_rstAddress.MoveFirst()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        Else : m_rstAddress.MoveFirst()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        End If


        m_rstAddress.Update()
        ShowCurrentRecord()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub



    Private Sub btnFirst_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
        If m_rstAddress.BOF Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the begninning of the file.", "BOF")
            m_rstAddress.MoveFirst()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        Else : m_rstAddress.MoveFirst()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
Elsee:      m_rstAddress.MovePrevious()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        If m_rstAddress.BOF Then

            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the end of this file.")
            m_rstAddress.MoveFirst()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        Else : m_rstAddress.MovePrevious()
            ShowCurrentRecord()

        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnLast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
        If m_rstAddress.BOF Then
            m_rstAddress.MoveLast()
            ShowCurrentRecord()
        Else : m_rstAddress.MoveLast()
            ShowCurrentRecord()


        End If
    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: It would help if you actually pointed out where it's failing.

Comment: It's failing to run the program.

Comment: Okay , but it will be failing at a specific point, If it's failing during the build process the errors window will tell you where, if it's failing during execution then you'll have a stack trace.  Look at the stack trace and then at the inner detail.  That should tell you where it's failing.  If we know that there's more chance that we might be able to help.

Comment: If you could trim down the code to the minimum necessary that would help us too. And it might give you a clue as to where the problem is.

Comment: The error is on this line - m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value(-lblPhone.Text) - If you read the question carefully the line # is included.

Comment: I suspect that you do not intend to have a label `Elsee` in `btnFirst_Click`. I recommend that you do not use the colon statement separator - just use another line.

Comment: @Samlaptop I have edited the format of the error message. It was unreasonably difficult to read in the format you used - the line number was *not* easy to see. And we don't get line numbers in the question unless you put them in. A comment next to the offending line would have made it easier to find. You could have edited out the irrelevant information, e.g project name, file, and suppresion state. You are more likely to get help if you help us to help you ;)

Comment: What an utterly useless title.  See [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates this line is incorrect:

```
m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value(-lblPhone.Text)
```

Should this not be set in the same way as the other fields?

```
m_rstAddress.Fields("Phone").Value = lblPhone.Text
```

Comment: It is also pointing to the Label and not the Textbox which looks a bit strange to me. So maybe it should even be txtPhone.Text. Pretty sure there is no overload for Value taking parameters. That would explain the error.